# Java: invoking method

Tags: java

In Java, I have something like this

```
public class A {
    private String title;
    public A () { 
    // do something
    }

    public void run () {
        B b = new B();
        b.run();
    }

    public void changeTitle(String newTitle) {
        this.title = newTitle;
    } 
}


public class B {
   public B() {
   // do something
   }
   public void run() {

   }
}
```

My question is in method run() of B, is it possible to invoke method changeTitle() in A to change the title of the instance of A that instantiates B?

Thanks

Comment: There is no implicit link between an object and the object that instantiated it. As the masses have said below, you need to make that connection explicit.

Comment: why not just execute it? thats the fastest way i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B` can only invoke methods on `A` if it contains a reference to an instance of `A`.  You could pass an instance of A into B to achieve this.

```
public void run () {
    B b = new B(this);
    b.run();
}

public class B {
   private A a;
   public B(A a) {
       this.a = a;
       a.changeTitle("Ha!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if B accepts a type A in its constructor, and when you say new B, pass in 'this' similar to

```
public void run () {
    B b = new B(this);
    b.run();
}
```

now you have a copy of the A object your working with.

Comment: Is it really a copy (ie. new instance) or a reference to the original instance of `A`?

Comment: thank subsub, I am by far not an expert on java as you can tell :D.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Pass an instance of `A` in the constructor for `B`.

Answer (score 0):

This will only be possible if you pass `this` as argument when you invoke B's run() method.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you arrange for instances of `B` to know what instance of `A` they should do that to (e.g., by passing that into the constructor for `B` and remembering it).

If you're doing something like this then you should consider, e.g., what you want to happen if an instance of `B` is created by something other than an instance of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

no. As such an instance of B does not know who created it.

However with B as:

```
public class B {
   private A creator;

   public B(A creator) {
      this.creator = creator;
      // do something
    ...
  }
```

and creating `new B(this)` in `A.run()`, B could call `creator.changeTitle("whatever")` in its run() method.

Answer (score 0):

Is B is a non static inner class of A you van invoke the mehods of A (and access its fieldes).